# API Routing in rails : how to handle many to many relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing

I have 4 models :

- Place, Event, Rsvp, User

A place can have many events.
There's a many to many relationship between Event and User through Rsvp.

I want to get all events for a place and i want to get all events for a user.

So my routes look like this :

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users do
        resources :events
      end
      resources :places do
        resources :events
      end
    end
  end
```

Now, if i call Get /users/1/events and Get /places/1/events i hit the EventsController#index.

My question is : how can i know which route is used to answer accordingly ?

Bonus question : am i on the right track or is there another way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: One will have `params[:user_id]` set and the other will have `params[:place_id]`

Comment: great ! that's it, it works :) Create the answer so that i can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One will have `params[:user_id]` set and the other will have `params[:place_id]`